# Array getting deleted from the selected element to the end of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

I am working on Booklist project. I have attached a card like pattern to each item of booklist i.e. each book. To each of them, there is a div that deletes that selected book when clicking on it. But in my case, the click to each div will delete that certain book but it will also delete all books from that index to the end of array.

```
function removeBookCard() {
  [...bookDelBtn].forEach((btn) =>
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      console.log("hi");
      let index = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.index;
      console.log(index);
      deleteBook(myLibrary, index);
      clearBookContainer();
      displayBooks();

    })
  );
}

function deleteBook(arr, index) {
  myLibrary = [...arr.slice(0, index), ...arr.slice(index + 1)];
  return myLibrary;
```

When running debugger, I noticed that once the goal was achieved the `btn.addEventListener("click", (e)` was called once again and the previous index of the item to which I clicked on was passed to `index`. I have no clue why this is happening as I only clicked once.

Here is the [repl](https://replit.com/@iwantroca/library#script.js)

Comment: You can remove an element from an array with [`arr.splice(index, 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: yes I tried that as well but it acts same, like i mentioned at last, event listener kinda run once again till that index is completely removed form the array.

Comment: You are listening the click event - deleting the item - and displaying  books `displayBooks` which is running `removeBookCard` again. I believe you need to remove the **removeBookCard** function inside **displayBooks**. But that needs a bit of refactoring your whole code.

Comment: I changed my approach to use add event listener to document instead. Currently working on it.